# OS X 10.11 library not found

Tags: xcode, macos, clang

I want to compile an app which using the libyaml. I have built it in OS X 10.10 successfully. But after upgrading to OS X 10.11, I just got the error message `ld: library not found for -lyaml`. libyaml is installed by Homebrew and locates on  `/usr/local/lib`. I can find `libyaml.dylib` in `/usr/local/lib`.

I have done the following:

- `csrutil disable` to disalbe System Integrity Protection which will prevent linking to external libraries in Recovery OS
- `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include` for looking for header file of libyaml
- `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` for looking for dynamic library of libyaml, that is `libyaml.dylib`

but still got the same error message.

Run `otool -L /usr/local/lib/libyaml.dylib` got:

```
/usr/local/lib/libyaml.dylib:
    /usr/local/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)
```

Platform: OS X 10.11, Xcode 7.0.1

How to solve this?

Comment: What's `csrutil`?  What does `C_INCLUDE_PATH` do?  A few more tags would help understand how you are building your executable and what's being passed to the linker.

Comment: Someone has told me the SIP would prevent linking to external dynamic libraries. Let me disable it. `C_INCLUDE_PATH` is for looking for header files of libyaml.

Comment: What "SIP"?  You really are leaving out lots of detail that might help someone help you.

Comment: SIP is for System Integrity Protection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just set `LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` to solve it.

Comment: LIBRARY_PATH affects build-time search path as documented here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.4.0/gcc/Environment-Variables.html. I could not find this in clang's documentation, but it honors this variable as well.